# Is there a program to convert assembly to C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a program that will convert assembly to C or C++?
I did a lot of searching but I could not find anything that works.
There is a program called "Boomerang"; it looks great and just want I wanted, but it's very unstable and crashes when I try to use it. ([boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/))

Are there any other free programs that will do that?

Comment: @PaulR That question was removed.

Comment: @JL2210: thanks - have now closed with a more useful duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a decompiler.

You will end up with something not really much better than the ASM source, and I'm pretty sure you're going to end up with C, not C++ anyway.

Comment: i don't think i want a decompiler, i have the assembly code but i want it turned into c++.

Answer (score 1):

There are few tools able to do the conversion like [Regolix](http://www.microapl.co.uk/asm2c/index.html) translator from ASM to C and [Datatek](http://www.assemblerconversion.com/dtk_conversion.html?t) converting ASM to C/C++/Cobol/C#. However, I think the maintenance of the converted code can be problematic.

Comment: yea i looked at both of thoses Relogix i don't understand i think it's built in and idk how to use it. and datatek you have to pay for it. i looked but i did not see anything about downloading you have to call them to talk about buying.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

It cannot be done.

It is beyond the grasp of mortals.

Well, unless the C code uses embedded assembly.  But even there it's a little iffy.

Note that a decompiler does not "convert assembly to C".  A decompiler attempts to *approximate* a program's original source code.  The mapping is not necessarily perfect, and not possible for arbitrary assembly (again, unless you use inline assembly in the resulting C).

Comment: Eh? No... it won't be perfect, but getting it to be at least a little bit higher level so it's easier to work with is still a good start.

Comment: -1 The maintenance of the decompiled code can be difficult but it can be done.

Comment: @zoli2k: no, for arbitrary assembly, it cannot be done.  The capabilities of C are not a loose superset of those of assembly language.  For example, let's say my assembly consists of "TST %r1".  This instruction causes the processor step counter to go up by 1, but if I don't use the result, has no other effect.  There is no C code which equates to this lone instruction.  There are many other examples - reading processor internal registers, writing to I/O devices directly, even the HLT instruction.  What I said was correct.

Comment: @Borealid, in sample conversions of Regolix there are also converted TST instructions. I absolutely agree with you, that writing that ASM is a different level of control over the hardware than C and some instructions can not be directly converted to C. On the other hand, if a tool is able to convert only 90% of the ASM code to C, that is already a lot of saved time. I will remove -1 if you add your examples with HLT and TST to the answer.

Comment: @zoli2k: An easy example is a function which consists of 10 HLT instructions.  This has no C equivalent.  Ditto one consisting of 10 "TST %r1".  Or, for instance, a program with no functions at all (see http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html ).  Just because the disassembler can find equivalents for *some* code containing the instructions does not mean it can do so for *all* uses of the instructions.  And what the poster asked for was a converter - i.e. an invertible mapping.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer so I can remove the vote down?

Comment: The funny thing is, for the game Transport Tycoons Deluxe (aka TTD), this very thing was done. Yes, it contained tons of `TST %r1` instructions. So? That just meant the decompiler emitted a macro.